# Is it required to reboot Ubuntu after joined a Windows Domain?

Tags: networking, server, bash, lubuntu, domain-server

I tried to automate linux installation and one of my step is to join Windows domain. Thanks to documentation and community i am able to join Windows domain using bash script. I do confirm from Windows 'ActiveDirectory Computers' that my Ubuntu VM is displayed.

The problem i have is that i cannot log in this Ubuntu VM using putty (or any ssh command) with Windows domain user account. If i want to log with user account then the only way I found was to reboot Ubuntu VM and only after that i can do remote with putty.

Is it required to reboot ? I have some remaining stuff to do in bash after joined the domain and it required to be able to log with a domain user account first.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

On Linux only when you need to switch a kernel a reboot is sort of needed but that is also not required. systemd works with services that can be restarted.
The service is `sssd` so `systemctl start sssd` or `systemctl restart sssd` will active it.

You do need to `realm join user={user} {host}` your user. You can use `realm list` to see if the connection is active. Config will be stored in  `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

Comment: I do confirm it works with your recommendation. Thx a lot rinzwind

Comment: @terry cool :-) thanks for the headsup. I like my answered to have that green checkmark :-D